# jQuery Autocomplete Turkish special character problems

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have problems with Turkish special characters my encoding system is ISO-8859-9 charset in headers and server.

```
//Database connections
include_once("ogr_con.php");
require_once("oraunit.php");

function strtoupper_tr($string){
  $upper=array("ü" => "Ü", "ö" => "Ö", "ğ" => "Ğ", "ş" => "Ş", "ç" => "Ç", "i" => "İ", "ı" => "I");
  return strtoupper(strtr($string,$upper));
}

function strtolower_tr($string){
  $low=array("Ü" => "ü", "Ö" => "ö", "Ğ" => "ğ", "Ş" => "ş", "Ç" => "ç", "İ" => "i", "I" => "ı");
  return strtolower(strtr($string,$low));
}

$adi= strtolower_tr($_GET["q"]);
$adi[0]=strtoupper($adi[0]);
$soyadi= strtoupper_tr($_GET["q"]);
if (!$adi) return;

$adiquery="SELECT K.ADI||' '||K.SOYADI AS FLNAME 
           FROM personel.kisi k 
           WHERE K.ADI LIKE '%".$adi."%' OR K.SOYADI LIKE '%".$soyadi."%')";
$aq=oraArray($con, $adiquery, array());
if(is_array($aq)){
    while(list($sno,$u)=each($aq)){
        $uadi = $u['FLNAME'];
        echo "$uadi\n";
    }
}
```

1. Functions `strtoupper_tr` and `strtolower_tr` not working for special characters.
2. `$uadi` - when this values is returned not displayed properly in textbox.

   `<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#fuadsoyad").autocomplete("get_name.php", {

      width: 260,

      matchContains: true,

      selectFirst: false

       });

   });

   </script>`

Can anyone help me solve this problem?
What do you advice me to do?

Comment: You need to use UTF-8 in everywhere. Selamlar.

Comment: The problem I cannot use Unicode other system is ISO-8859-9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Autocomplete case sensitive for utf-8 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237394/jquery-autocomplete-case-sensitive-for-utf-8-characters)

Answer (score 1):

A general advice when dealing with special characters : use the [**UTF-8**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/UTF-8) charset : it should support all characters your application will require, no matter what language you need.

And it'll facilitate things when working with Ajax, as the standard charset for Ajax is UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Let me explain how in case anyone might face it in the future.
Select all needed data and put it in one variable as shown below as $hocalist

```
$adiquery="SELECT K.ADI||' '||K.SOYADI AS FLNAME 
           FROM personel.kisi k 
           WHERE K.ADI LIKE '%".$adi."%' OR K.SOYADI LIKE '%".$soyadi."%')";

$aq=oraArray($con, $adiquery, array());
$hocalist = "";
foreach($aq as $row) {
$hocalist .= ($hocalist != "" ? "," : "")."{label:'".addslashes($row[FLNAME])."',ID:'$row[KNO]'}";
}
```

After that pass this variable as an array to JS as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var hocalistesi = new Array(<?= $hocalist; ?>);
$("#fuadsoyad").autocomplete(hocalistesi, {
minChars: 0,
max: 50,
width: 460,
autoFill: false,
matchContains: true,
formatItem: function(row, i, max) {
 return row.label;
},
formatMatch: function(row, i, max) {
 return row.label;
},
formatResult: function (row) {
 return row.label;
}
});
});
</script>
```

Of course if we talk about efficiency it is not that efficient but working with different character sets it might be accepted as solution.
Hope will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the `.js` file itself as "Unicode", for example in Notepad:
Save As --> Encoding drop down --> Unicode

Answer (score 0):

See the following [blog](http://www.buyukozdogan.com/dotclear2/index.php?tpost/en/2011/04/20/klavye_en&navlang=en),
It proposes a keyboard extension. The full list of combinations is:

- for the letter 'ğ', use 'Alt Gr' +'g';
- for the letter 'ş', use 'Alt Gr' + 's';
- for the letter 'ç', use 'Alt Gr' + 'c';
- for the letter 'ü', use 'Alt Gr' +
  'u';
- for the letter 'ö', use 'Alt Gr' +
  'o';
- for the letter 'ı', use 'Alt Gr' +
  'i'.

Answer (score 0):

try iconv("windows-1254","UTF-8",$text);